# Libraries in d3.js to create a Piano Chart

Tags: d3.js

Are there any libraries for d3.js or examples that create piano charts eg http://www.zingchart.com/gallery/chart/?id=28536

Comment: d3 /is/ the library for this. Did you look at any of the examples on the d3 wiki?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian, are you saying that zingchart is built on d3?  That doesn't help unless the source is available. There's no d3 code in that page that I can find.  OP is trying to figure out how to do something like this him/herself.  I can't claim that there's not a very similar plot on the wiki--there's a lot of stuff there--but I have not seen it.  (Of course all of the components of the zinchart example exist in various examples in the wiki gallery, but I think it's a reasonable question to ask whether someone has illustrated how to put together the whole package, or something like it.)

Comment: This visualization certainly seems possible to do with D3.js, but I actually advise you against implementing it. When it comes to rectangles where the width and length both change, we don't judge them as accurately, and we tend to underestimate the differences in size. The best practice is to scale rectangles by changing only one linear dimension, that is, using bars. Just make this a multiple bar chart.